# Deploy WSO2 API Manager in existing tomcat

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I already have tomcat running, can I only have war file of WSO2 API Manager to deploy on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is not possible as we have many config files and dependencies with api-manager which are required at runtime.

API manager is a server and it is not a webapp.